# Simple arithmetic on values retreived using OIDs

Tags: math, snmp, ram, nagios, mib

I am new to SNMP and Nagios, and would like to do some basic arithmetic on values retrieved using OIDs.

I need to monitor the used memory (RAM) on the servers on the University's network. They seem to be using UCD-SNMP-MIB. So far I have encountered `memTotalReal.0` and `memAvailReal.0`, and no direct way to retrieve the used memory. Is there any specific reason for this?

Expected command for basic subtraction:

```
$USER1$/check_snmp -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -o memTotalReal.0-memAvailReal.0
```

What is the easiest way to retrieve the used memory? Do I need to resort to subtraction by possibly writing another script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to do it. So you need to calculate it like this:

```
(Used – buffers – cached) / Total * 100 = % memory used

Used = total - available
```

In terms of OIDs you'll need to use the following:

- memTotalOID = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.5.0'
- memRealAvailOID = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0'
- memRealBuffersOID = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.14.0'
- memRealCachedOID = '.1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.15.0'